# How to change the view or content when switching apps on Cordova Android?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I was trying to use `onPause` to tell the JavaScript to show a special view, but it only shows after I switch back to the app from background to foreground.

Also, is there any way to blur the view in order to secure the content when the multi-tasking view is being displayed? Like I can use `UIBlurEffect`+`UIVisualEffectView` for iOS, but I can't find anything on Android.

Comment: I searched a little bit, there was a solution to hide the content by adding this configuration: android:excludeFromRecent, and the view is called "Overview screen of Android".